# Is it possible to pass a string to a interface? Or at lest fetch from SharedPreferences inside a interface?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to fetch a stored JWT from the SharedPreferences so I can send them as a Header in my requrest but I'm not able to get that data inside the API interface. Is this possible?

Thanks

---

**SOLVED:**

For anyone looking for this: you can pass a Header as a param, ex.:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("users/getUser")
Call<String> getUser(
        @Header("Token") String token,
        @Field("user") String user
);
```

Comment: Which library do you use for networking?

Comment: I'm using retrofit2, but I found that I can pass Header as a param

Answer (score 1):

also you can use an integrated `Interceptor` to adding this token on ALL requests like this:

```
public class AuthInterceptor
    implements Interceptor {
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain)
        throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    request = request.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Token", new MySharedPref().getToken())
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

and after that add an instance of it on your `OkHttpClient` :

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(new AuthInterceptor());
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
       ...
        .client(httpClient.build())

        .build();
```

Comment: That looks cool. But the thing is that I'm now always using an auth token